# Setting root and passing parameter using the same function in angular 2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I am building an Ionic2 app. On click, I am sending parameter and setting a new rootPage in the same function so I can display a different set of tabs on the destination page.

```
   viewProjects(item){
    this.navCtrl.push(ItemPage,{
       item: item
     });
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Tabs2Page);
  }
```

Template:

```
<button  ion-item (click)="viewItem(item)"> Item </button></div>
```

If I don't send parameter on click, I can successfully go to the target page and new rootPage is set.

```
   viewProjects(item){
    this.navCtrl.push(ItemPage);
    this.navCtrl.setRoot(Tabs2Page);
  }
```

If I only send Parameter and not setRoot, It works I have access to the parameters that I need but new rootPage is not set so I don't have tabs on the page.

```
   viewProjects(item){
    this.navCtrl.push(ItemPage,{
       item: item
     });
  }
```

I'm getting the following error

```
Runtime Error
Error in ./ItemPage class ItemPage - caused by: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

I need to be able to setRoot and be able to send parameters on click, any idea how I might be able to do that? Thanks a lot !